# Looking for resources on irregular expander graphs

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, graph-theory, directed-graphs

I've been reading up on Expander graphs on the web, papers, books and surveys.

However, all the resources I could find on Google is about regular, connected, non-bipartite (undirected) graphs. The only thing I managed to find about irregular expander graphs is [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1559831/non-regular-expander-graph). The answer to that directs to "Recent Progress In General Topology III" which I have been unable to get my hands on.

I would appreciate if anyone could point me to a readily available resource about non-regular expanders (directed ones if possible) as I would like to know how the lack of regularity would affect the properties of expanders. Specifically, I would like to know if there is a variant of the the "Expander Mixing Lemma" for general digraphs.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you seen any version of the expander mixing lemma even for *regular* directed graphs?

Comment: Actually it is the first one I saw. See lemma 4.15 [here](https://people.seas.harvard.edu/~salil/cs225/spring09/lecnotes/Chap4.pdf).

Comment: We should be able to imitate that proof for general digraphs, but with a slightly altered conclusion. There is still a random walk adjacency matrix, but the stationary distribution $\pi$ is not uniform. If we measure the size of a set $S$ not by its size $|S|$ but by something like $\sum_{i \in S} \pi_i$, we might be able to get a result that predicts $e(S,T)$ based on this measure of $S$ and of $T$, with an error based on the second eigenvalue of the random walk matrix.